# Magento 1.9.1.0 Customer Unable Login Chrome Browser Only

Tags: magento-1.9, chrome-browser

Strange situation with Magento Customer login for Chrome only (and mobile chrome browser).

Users can not login via customer/account/login/

They can login via checkout/onepage/

I have added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

to login.phtml underneath:

```
<ul class="form-list">
```

in

- template/persistent/checkout/onepage
- template/persistent/customer/form

I have increased the Cookie Lifetime to 33600 I have set the cookie domain (as recommended by a post on a forum, apprently google can be funny with cookies and there source).

Cache is all cleared in browsers and in var/cache and cleared in admin.
Sessions are cleared and session folder is set to 755 file permissions.

Any help at all would be appreciated

Comment: is cookie setting issue in chrome else cookie setting issue at magento admin

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean I increased the cookie lifetime in magento admin and set the cookie domain in mageno admin

Comment: Can you confirm that there is a cookie in Chrome with the name frontend or adminhtml

Comment: there is indeed when first visiting the website a cookie is created called frontend, when attempting to login another one is created and given the same value. I can login to admin perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by removing all the files and doing a fresh install, reapply the theme I was able to overcome this issue.